# Compare current element in one list to next element in another list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two equally long lists representing the start and end frames of an event. They look something like this:

```
START     END
111        113
118        133
145        186
```

The next element of the START list is always going to be bigger than the previous element in the END lists a.k.a 118 is always going to be bigger than 113. I am trying to calculate the difference between the next element of the START list to the previous element in the END list a.k.a 118-113. I want to do this for every element, however I am having difficulties accessing the elements for the proper calculation. Here is what I have so far:

```
def estimateAverageBlinkInterval(blinkStartFrame, blinkStopFrame):
    
    estimateAverage = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(blinkStartFrame)):
        print(blinkStartFrame)
        for j in range(0, len(blinkStopFrame)):
            print(blinkStopFrame[j])
            estimateAverage.append(blinkStartFrame[i+1]-blinkStopFrame[j])
        
    return mean(estimateAverage)
```

I am essentially iterating over both lists, I tried 'blinkStartFrame[:-1]' at the for loop but that doesn't do anything and with the current [i+1] I am getting an 'IndexError: list index out of range' which makes sense as i am trying to access and element the loop hasn't iterated over yet. Any suggestions are more than welcome, thank you!

Comment: can you provide the python objects for your two list? (what you showed are not lists)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @holydragon The expected output would be the difference, so if we would be to use the example I have given above: 118-113, 145-133 etc. After appending these elements I want to get their mean which would just be a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this that you're looking for ?
You can compare start[i] with end[i-1] ?

```
start = [111,118, 145]
end = [113, 133, 186]

for i in range(1, len(start)):
    print(start[i] - end[i-1])
```

Comment: Note that here we iterate from `1` to `len(start)` which is one less than the lenght of the list. This is the key issue which made it not work in the question.

Comment: The opener want the difference between the frames, so if we have a list of 3 frames, we can only have 2 transitions no ? She explains it in a comment under the first post

Comment: Thats exactly what I am saying. You did everything correct. I just wantet to highlight that fact. Maybe you could explicitly state this in your answer to further improove it ;)

Comment: Oops sorry for misunderstanding Felix

Comment: This solution worked lovely for me thank you, I see my mistake now!

Answer (score 1):

**Concept**

Loop for `n-1` rounds where `n` is the length of the arrays (assume both have equal length). In each loop, find the difference between `i+1` (next start) and `i` (previous end), and put the result into an array `diff`. That's it. If you want `mean`, then just sum it up and divide it with its length.

**Code**

```
start = [111,118,145]
end = [113,133,186]
diff = []
for i in range(len(start)-1):
    diff.append(start[i+1]-end[i])
print(diff)
mean = sum(diff)/len(diff)
print(mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct. You just need to make it more simpler and handle the exceptions.

1. You don't need two loops to solve it. -> only one loop is enough.
2. You will have the error `IndexError`, because `blinkStopFrame[-1]` is not valid. -> need to except the index 0
3. You will also have the error `IndexError` too, if the two arrays don't have the same length. -> need to check the length of second array

By the way, you can try this to fill the `estimateAverage`.

```python
for index, value in enumerate(blinkStartFrame):
    if index == 0:
        continue
    if (index - 1) >= len(blinkStopFrame):
        break
    estimateAverage.append(value - blinkStopFrame[index -1])
```

Comment: Is there a problem with how I currently fill the estimateAverage or is this just a more elegant solution? :)

Comment: @StefaniDimitrova, i added some explanation about your mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

If both START and END are numpy arrays and have equal length then:

```
est = START[1:] - END[:-1]
mean_est = np.mean(est)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def estimateAverageBlinkInterval(blinkStartFrame, blinkStopFrame):
    
    estimateAverage = [start-stop for start, stop in zip(blinkStopFrame[1:], blinkStartFrame[:-1])]
    return sum(estimateAverage)/len(estimateAverage)


start = [111, 118, 145]
end = [113, 133, 186]
print(estimateAverageBlinkInterval(start, end))
```